# Downloading/Exporting sites Search Results by using Export button in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to use Python to scrape data from the following website (with sample query): https://par.nsf.gov/**search**/fulltext:NASA%20NOAA%20coral

However instead of scraping the search results, I realized that it would just be easier if I somehow click on the Save Results as "CSV" link in a programmatic way and work with that CSV data instead as it would free me from having to navigate all the pages of the search results.

I inspected the CSV link element and found it called an "exportSearch('csv') function.
[image: Inspecting CSV export link element]

By typing the function's name into the console I found that the CSV link is just setting window.location.href to: https://par.nsf.gov/**export/format:csv**/fulltext:NASA%20NOAA%20coral 
[image] 
If I follow that link in the same browser, the save prompt will open up with a csv to save.

My issue starts when I want to do replicate this process using python. If I try to call the export link directly using the Requests library, the response is empty.

```
url = "https://par.nsf.gov/export/format:csv/fulltext:" + urllib.parse.quote("NASA NOAA coral")
print("URL: ", url)
response = requests.get(url)
print("Response: ", len(response.content))
```

Can someone show me what I'm missing? I don't know how to first establish search results on the website's server that I can then access for export using Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to download the file in python using the `urllib` library.

```
# Include your search term
url = "https://par.nsf.gov/export/format:csv//filter-results:F/term:" + urllib.parse.quote("NASA NOAA coral")
print("URL: ", url)

import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)

# here you can also specify the path where you want to download the file like
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'/Users/Downloads/)


# Run this command only when you face an SSL certificate error, generally it occurs for Mac users with python 3.6 .
# Run this in jupyter notebook
!open /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command

# On terminal just run
open /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Similarly you can also use `wget` to fetch your file:

```
url = "https://par.nsf.gov/export/format:csv//filter-results:F/term:" + urllib.parse.quote("NASA NOAA coral")
print("URL: ", url)

import wget
wget.download(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the link to download the CSV is here:

```
https://par.nsf.gov/export/format:csv//term:your_search_term
```

`your_search_term` is URL encoded

in your case, the link is: https://par.nsf.gov/export/format:csv//filter-results:F/term:NASA%20NOAA%20coral

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing some cookies that didn't come up when you do a simple requests GET (e.g. WT_FPC).

To get around this I used selenium's webdriver to do an initial GET request and use the cookies from that request to set up in the POST request for downloading the CSV data.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = "path to chrome driver"
with requests.Session() as session:
    url = "https://par.nsf.gov/search/fulltext:" + urllib.parse.quote("NASA NOAA coral")

    #GET fetches website plus needed cookies
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chrome_path)
    browser.get(url)        

    ## Session is set with webdriver's cookies
    request_cookies_browser = browser.get_cookies()
    [session.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value']) for c in request_cookies_browser]

    url = "https://par.nsf.gov/export/format:csv/fulltext:" + urllib.parse.quote("NASA NOAA coral")

    response = session.post(url)
    ## No longer empty 
    print(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```